# Lagom service consuming input from Kafka

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, lagom

I am trying to figure out how Lagom can be used to consume data from external systems communicating over Kafka.

I've ran into this [section of Lagom documentation](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/MessageBrokerApi.html#Subscribe-to-a-topic), which describes how Lagom service can communicate with another Lagom service by subscribing to its topic.

```
helloService
  .greetingsTopic()
  .subscribe // <-- you get back a Subscriber instance
  .atLeastOnce(
  Flow.fromFunction(doSomethingWithTheMessage)
)
```

However, what is the appropriate configuration when you want to subscribe to a Kafka topic that contains events produced by some random, external system?

Is some sort of adapter needed for this functionality?
To clarify, I have this at the moment:

```
object Aggregator {
  val TOPIC_NAME = "my-aggregation"
}

trait Aggregator extends Service {
  def aggregate(correlationId: String): ServiceCall[Data, Done]

  def aggregationTopic(): Topic[DataRecorded]

  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._

    named("aggregator")
      .withCalls(
        pathCall("/api/aggregate/:correlationId", aggregate _)
      )
      .withTopics(
        topic(Aggregator.TOPIC_NAME, aggregationTopic())
          .addProperty(
            KafkaProperties.partitionKeyStrategy,
            PartitionKeyStrategy[DataRecorded](_.sessionData.correlationId)
          )
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

And I can invoke it via simple POST request.
However, I would like for it to be invoked by consuming `Data` messages from some (external) Kafka topic.

I was wondering if there is such a way to configure the descriptor in a fashion similar to this mockup:

```
override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
  ...
  kafkaTopic("my-input-topic")
    .subscribe(serviceCall(aggregate _)
    .withAtMostOnceDelivery
}
```

I've ran into this [discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lagom-framework/H7DZzwhrW7o), but in the OPs questions, I do not see he is actually doing anything with `EventMessage`s coming from `some-topic` except routing them to the topic defined by his service.

### EDIT #1: Progress update

Looking at the documentation, I decided to try the following approach.
I added 2 more modules, `aggregator-kafka-proxy-api` and `aggregator-kafka-proxy-impl`.

In new api module, I defined a new service, with no methods, but one topic which would represent my Kafka topic:

```
object DataKafkaPublisher {
  val TOPIC_NAME = "data-in"
}

trait DataKafkaPublisher extends Service {
  def dataInTopic: Topic[DataPublished]

  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._
    import DataKafkaPublisher._

    named("data-kafka-in")
      .withTopics(
        topic(TOPIC_NAME, dataInTopic)
          .addProperty(
            KafkaProperties.partitionKeyStrategy,
            PartitionKeyStrategy[SessionDataPublished](_.data.correlationId)
          )
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

In the impl module, I simply did the standard implementation

```
class DataKafkaPublisherImpl(persistentEntityRegistry: PersistentEntityRegistry) extends DataKafkaPublisher {
  override def dataInTopic: Topic[api.DataPublished] =
    TopicProducer.singleStreamWithOffset {
      fromOffset =>
        persistentEntityRegistry.eventStream(KafkaDataEvent.Tag, fromOffset)
          .map(ev => (convertEvent(ev), ev.offset))
    }

  private def convertEvent(evt: EventStreamElement[KafkaDataEvent]): api.DataPublished = {
    evt.event match {
      case DataPublished(data) => api.DataPublished(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to actually consume these events, in my `aggregator-impl` module, I added a "subscriber" service, which takes these events, and invokes appropriate commands on entity.

```
class DataKafkaSubscriber(persistentEntityRegistry: PersistentEntityRegistry, kafkaPublisher: DataKafkaPublisher) {

  kafkaPublisher.dataInTopic.subscribe.atLeastOnce(
    Flow[DataPublished].mapAsync(1) { sd =>
      sessionRef(sd.data.correlationId).ask(RecordData(sd.data))
    }
  )

  private def sessionRef(correlationId: String) =
    persistentEntityRegistry.refFor[Entity](correlationId)
}
```

This effectively allowed me to publish a message on Kafka topic "data-in", which was then proxied and converted to `RecordData` command before issued to the entity to consume.

However, it seems somewhat hacky to me. I am coupled to Kafka by Lagom internals. I cannot swap the source of my data easily. For example, how would I consume external messages from RabbitMQ if I wanted to?
What if I'm trying to consume from another Kafka (different one than used by Lagom)?

### Edit #2: More docs

I've found a few articles on Lagom docs, notably, this:

[Consuming Topics from 3rd parties](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/KafkaClient.html#Consuming-Topics-from-3rd-parties)

> You may want your Lagom service to consume data produced on services
>   not implemented in Lagom. In that case, as described in the Service
>   Clients section, you can create a third-party-service-api module in
>   your Lagom project. That module will contain a Service Descriptor
>   declaring the topic you will consume from. Once you have your
>   ThirdPartyService interface and related classes implemented, you
>   should add third-party-service-api as a dependency on your
>   fancy-service-impl. Finally, you can consume from the topic described
>   in ThirdPartyService as documented in the Subscribe to a topic
>   section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer was provided by Alan Klikic on Lightbend discussion forums [here](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/lagom-service-consuming-input-from-kafka/3450/11).

Part 1:

> If you are only using external Kafka cluster in your business service
>   then you can implement this using only Lagom Broker API.   So you need
>   to:
>
> 1. create API with service descriptor with only topic definition (this API is not beeing implemented)
> 2. in your business service configure kafka_native depending on your deployment (as i mentioned in previous post)
> 3. in your business service inject service from API created in #1 and subscribe to it using Lagom Broker API subscriber
>
> Offset commiting, in Lagom Broker API subscriber is handled
>   out-of-the-box.

Part 2:

> Kafka and AMQP consumer implementations require persistant akka
>   stream. So you need to handle disconnects.   These can be done in two
>   ways:
>
> 1. control peristant akka stream by wraping it in an actor. You initialize you stream Flow on actor preStart and pipe stream complete
>      to the actor that will stop it. If stream completes or fails actor
>      will stop. Then wrap actor in actor backoff with restart strategy,
>      that will restart the actor in case of complete or fail and
>      reinitialize the Flow
> 2. akka streams Delayed restarts with backoff stage
>
> Personnaly I use #1 and did not try #2 yet.
>
> Initializing backoff actor for #1 or Flow for #2 can be done in your
>   Lagom components trait (basically in the same place where you do your
>   subscribe now using Lagom Broker API).
>
> Be sure to set a consumer group when configuring consumer to ensure
>   avoiding duplicate consuming. You can use, like Lagom does, service
>   name from descriptor as consumer group name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `lagom` so this is maybe just an idea. But as `akka-streams` is part of `lagom` (at least I assume that) - to get from this solution to what you need should be easy.

I used **[akka-stream-kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html)** and this went really nice (I only did a Prototype)

As you consume messages you would do something:

```
     Consumer
      .committableSource(
          consumerSettings(..), // config of Kafka
          Subscriptions.topics("kafkaWsPathMsgTopic")) // Topic to subscribe
      .mapAsync(10) { msg =>
        business(msg.record) // do something
      }
```

Check the well written [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html)

My whole example you find here: 
[PathMsgConsumer](https://github.com/pme123/play-binding-petstore/blob/master/server/app/pme123/petstore/server/control/PathMsgConsumer.scala)

Comment: I am aware that `akka-streams` comes with Lagom, and it has occurred to me I might use it on in/out boundaries, but I want to know if there is a recommended, idiomatic way for this. Nevertheless, I'll try your approach!